# Has GoodData already been accredited for Salesforce1 Mobile app?

Tags: salesforce, gooddata

Has GoodData already been officially accredited by Salesforce.com as to be properly designed to accept accesses from mobile or tablet devices through the Salesforce1 Mobile app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, we don't have certification like this. Anyway, you can use our HTML5 App and use it on all devices. What is the complete use case here?

Thanks!

JT

Comment: Typical user case for technical review by Salesforce is assumed as to confirm whether it is able for mobile or tablet users to confortably view and operate visual force pages to which GoodData dashboards have been embedded.

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21768/how-does-salesforce-classify-an-app-as-salesforce1-ready